# Send image file in FormData node JS ends with error

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, form-data

This is my function in my node JS script:

```
const uploadFile = async () => {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync('scripts/pose.png')
  const formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('file', buffer, 'dummyName.png')

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
  }

  const response = await axios.post(
    `${process.env.URL}/v1/files`,
    formData,
    {
      headers
    },
  )

  return response
}
```

no matter what I'm doing it's not working... with this code I'm getting an error:
"source.on is not a function"

Can someone help me, I tried literally everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const uploadFile = async () => {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(
    'scripts/pose.png',
  );
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', buffer, {
    filename: 'dummyName.png',
    contentType: 'image/jpeg', // Adjust the content type accordingly
  });

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    ...formData.getHeaders(),
  };

  const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.URL}/v1/files`, formData, {
    headers,
  });

  return response;
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I want to be sure i understand your question. but if what you are trying to do is upload an image from a form, you can use multer for it. it's quite easy to use and understand.

check them on npmjs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: hey :)
I'm trying to read a file in nodeJS and send it to a route via formData...
Unfortunately it's event not arriving to the route, because it's throwing an error when I'm appending the file to the formData

Comment: @MayAsk Have you imported `FormData` module to your script? I mean it's not natively included in Nodejs, it originates to browsers only.